# Use java classes available package in JSP?

Tags: jsp, package

I am new in JSP development. I have run simple .jsp files. Noe I have problem of using classes available in package. I have app dir in webapp dir in app dir I have all .jsp files and package named mypack. The mypack contains classes  which I want to use in .jsp file in app dir. But I get error of 500 while I want to run the .jsp file which contains class of mypack package.

```
Example: Example1.jsp

   <%@page contentType="text/html"%>    
   <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ page import="mypack.Display" %>
   <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>    
   <%
       Display cnt=new Display();
       String outpt=cnt.echoVar("Hi da");
       out.println(outpt);
   %>

Counter.java

    package mypack;

    public class Display
     {
          public String echoVar(String var){
        return var;
     }
     }
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: What happens if you don't use the display class? Try printing a string without the display class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Java` files goes under `src` and then your packages.
`JSP` files goes under `webapp` or `WebContent` (in eclipse) directory which should contain `WEB-INF` directory.

Example: [image]

This should help more : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout